# printf with the FormatMessage function

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to learn some WinAPI stuff, and was using the RegOpenKeyEx function. I have this code:

```
LPCTSTR subKey;
subKey = TEXT("WinSide");
HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
DWORD options = 0;
REGSAM samDesired = KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE;
HKEY hResult;


long openKey = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, subKey, options, samDesired, &hResult);

    if (( openKey == ERROR_SUCCESS))
    {
        printf_s("Registry subkey opened! \n");


    }

    else
    {


    char *errorMsg = NULL;
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
        NULL,openKey, 0, (LPSTR)&errorMsg,0,NULL);

    printf("Error code %i: %s\n", openKey, errorMsg);
    LocalFree(errorMsg);


    }

RegCloseKey(hResult);
```

The problem is that, if for example the key doesn't exist, printf shows:

> Error code 2: T

Can anyone help me?

I'm using latest Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: What if you use `FormatMessageA` instead of `FormatMessage`?

Comment: Awesome, @MikeCAT! I cannot mark your comment as answer, but, if you do answer the question, I will mark it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormatMessage` is a macro and will be `FormatMessageW`, which uses Unicode, or `FormatMessageA`, which uses ANSI code, depending on whether macro `UNICODE` is defined.

You pass `char**` to the function, so you should use `FormatMessageA` instead of `FormatMessage` to have it use ANSI code explicitly, and remove the cast to `LPSTR`.

Answer (score 1):

You should code using tchar.h defines, this way your code will work both on UNICODE and non-Unicode builds. This means, instead of `char` use `TCHAR`, `TCHAR` will resolve to wchar_t on UNICODE build, and to char on non-UNICODE. `LPSTR` should be `LPTSTR` (additional T inside). Your printf should be:

```
_tprintf(_T("Error code %i: %s\n"), openKey, errorMsg);
```

so the correct code should look like;

```
TCHAR *errorMsg = NULL;
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
    NULL,openKey, 0, (LPTSTR)&errorMsg,0,NULL);

_tprintf(_T("Error code %i: %s\n"), openKey, errorMsg);
LocalFree(errorMsg);
```

I suppose your problem is due to the fact that you are compiling on UNICODE build but using non - UNICODE strings/functions.

Comment: Just awesome! I suppose I have to learn how to use tchar.h defines when writing Win32 apps. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Checho: You don't have to use generic text mappings (unless you want to target Win 9x versions of Windows). You have to know, what the text mappings do, but you can go ahead and use `wchar_t` throughout any new code.

Comment: *"this way your code will work both on UNICODE and non-Unicode builds"* - A common misconception. It will **compile** for both ANSI and Unicode character encodings. It will, most likely, not work, since string handling is usually different between ANSI and Unicode strings. In general, you'll have to implement different algorithms.

Comment: Difference: *"compiles"* is not the same as *"works"*, as you imply. In general, it doesn't work, even though it compiles.

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski the code above should work, but IInspectable is right that in the general case there quite a few differences that make it sometimes painful to use TCHAR e.g. when having to deal with libraries that do not have TCHAR versions.

Comment: @CyberSpock: It's not just painful. Suggesting that code using generic text mappings will work as-is is dangerous. It will break, unless you write two code paths. As an example, [_istleadbyte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dawbheet.aspx) will always return `false`, when `_UNICODE` is defined. And now your code that skips over code units to find the beginning of the next character won't work for Unicode. Similarly, [_tcsinc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0hs2ad.aspx) recognizes multibyte-character sequences for MBCS encoding only, and fails for Unicode surrogates.